# Pass value of JavaScript variable to Rails view with hidden_field_tag helper

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I set up a JavaScript program using jQuery to change the user input values at various form field.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#billAmt").keyup(function(){
        var a = $("#billAmt").val();
        var b = a*3/100;
        var d = "<%= current_user.balance %>";
        var c = d - b;
        $("#cashBack").val(b);
        $("#total").val(c);
    });
});
```

This JavaScript code is inside the `form_tag` and I would like to pass #cashBack to hidden field.

I did like:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :cashBack, nil, :id => "cashBack", :value => ''%>
```

When I submit the form, `params[:cashBack]` is empty. So, how do I pass the value and change every time I change the value.

Comment: can you show me what you get a,b,c in keyup event

Comment: I pass a value in text field with id billAmt. Lets say I enter 100 and user balance is 200 then  a = 100, b=3, c = 197

Comment: this value didi you got when you `console.log()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to set hidden textfield, You must use pure javascript instead of JQuery.

```
$("#cashBack").get(0).value = b;
```

Comment: This is the so far the best answer for how to pass variable from javascript to hidden_field/rails erb. Simple and it works like a charm. Thank you ;) Can you describe why we cannot use jQuery and what method get do?